# Does the limit of 15 edits also include the tag-wiki edits?

Tags: support, edits, tag-wiki, rate-limiting

Today I have edited some tag wikis on *English Language & Usage*; when I edited a question of mine (right some minutes before writing this question), I was said I have already edited 15 posts of mine. As far as I recall, and [my activity](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/252/kiamlaluno?tab=activity&sort=revisions&page=1) seems to agree with me: I have not edited 15 posts of mine. The last 15 edits (and more) were all for tag wikis.

Are those included in the daily limit of edits for own posts?
As far as I can see, tag wikis are shown as created by the Community user, when the user who creates the tag wiki is not a 20K user, such as in [this case](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/36562/revisions).

Comment: *15* edits? I thought the limit was 5 edits. I get burned by this all the time when doing the digests.

Comment: I can try again, and see which number I get. I am sure the message said 15, though.

Comment: Sigh! It is too late: It is past midnight UTC, and the count has been reset, now. It was better I would have taken a screenshot. Sometimes I feel so dumb. `:(`

Comment: Well, it [was five at some time](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=1038504#1038504) anyway. Perhaps it's changed since then (which would be nice!)

Comment: I got a confirmation from a moderator: It's not 5. I don't know if that is important, but if it is not even the limit it should show, then something is not correct.